# How to create a dynamic fields in admin form?

Tags: admin, magento2.3, adminform, php-7.2

I want to add **add new button** template in admin form like this...

[image]

How to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: are you using blocks or UI components

Comment: ui component....

Answer (score 3):

Configure the **container** with XML

Just create a `NameSpace/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml` file with this content:

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">  
<fieldset name="my_fieldset" class="My\Module\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">More Product Links</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1000</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</fieldset>
```

**Dynamically create fields with PHP**

This is where we will write our custom logic to inject fields into this fieldset.

So here is the `NameSpace\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset` **PHP** class which.

```
<?php  
 namespace My\Module\Ui\Component\Form;


 use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;  
 use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentInterface;  
 use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\FieldFactory;  
 use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset as BaseFieldset;

 class Fieldset extends BaseFieldset  
 {
/**
 * @var FieldFactory
 */
private $fieldFactory;

public function __construct(
    ContextInterface $context,
    array $components = [],
    array $data = [],
    FieldFactory $fieldFactory)
{
    parent::__construct($context, $components, $data);
    $this->fieldFactory = $fieldFactory;
}

/**
 * Get components
 *
 * @return UiComponentInterface[]
 */
public function getChildComponents()
{
    $fields = [
        [
            'label' => __('Field Label From Code'),
            'value' => __('Field Value From Code'),
            'formElement' => 'input',
        ],
        [
            'label' => __('Another Field Label From Code'),
            'value' => __('Another Field Value From Code'),
            'formElement' => 'input',
        ],
        [
            'label' => __('Yet Another Field Label From Code'),
            'value' => __('Yet Another Field Value From Code'),
            'formElement' => 'input',
        ]
    ];

    foreach ($fields as $k => $fieldConfig) {
        $fieldInstance = $this->fieldFactory->create();
        $name = 'my_dynamic_field_' . $k;

        $fieldInstance->setData(
            [
                'config' => $fieldConfig,
                'name' => $name
            ]
        );

        $fieldInstance->prepare();
        $this->addComponent($name, $fieldInstance);
    }

    return parent::getChildComponents();
}
}
```

**NOTE :** In above logic i added simple field. so you need to add logic for add more field using **Jquery** or **Javascript** or any other logic. i have give a simple logic how to add dynamic UI component field.

Comment: Hey @Chirag  it's working good but now i want to use another fileld set field value in dynamic field file. so how i can get that details

Comment: Let me check if I found something.

Answer (score 2):

> app/code/Vendor/Name/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="sd_general" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Prince</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="sd_homepage" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top sd-general-admin-tab-general</class>
            <label>My generated form</label>
            <tab>sd_general</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_Name::home_page</resource>
            <group id="menus" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Breadcrumbs</label>
                <field id="menu_item" translate="label" sortOrder="15" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Create breadcrumb</label>
                    <frontend_model>Vendor\Name\Block\Adminhtml\Menu\Field\AdditionalBreadcrumb</frontend_model>
                    <backend_model>Vendor\Name\Block\Adminhtml\Menu\Config\Backend\AdditionalBreadcrumb</backend_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Name/Block/Adminhtml/Menu/Field/AdditionalBreadcrumb.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Name\Block\Adminhtml\Menu\Field;

use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray;

class AdditionalBreadcrumb extends AbstractFieldArray
{
    protected $_typeblockOptions;
    protected $_cmsblockOptions;
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _prepareToRender()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'titre',
            [
                'label' => __('Label'),
                'size' => '200px',
                'class' => 'required-entry'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'lien',
            [
                'label' => __('Url'),
                'size' => '200px'
            ]
        );


        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add Breadcrumb');
    }

    protected function _getGroupTypeRenderer()
    {
        if (!$this->_typeblockOptions) {
            $this->_typeblockOptions = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Vendor\Name\Block\Adminhtml\Menu\Config\Backend\TypeOptions::class,
                '',
                ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
            );
            $this->_typeblockOptions->setClass('type_group_select');
        }
        return $this->_typeblockOptions;
    }

    protected function _getGroupCmsBlocRenderer()
    {
        if (!$this->_cmsblockOptions) {
            $this->_cmsblockOptions = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Vendor\Name\Block\Adminhtml\Menu\Config\Backend\CmsBlockOptions::class,
                '',
                ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
            );
            $this->_cmsblockOptions->setClass('cmsbloc_group_select');
        }
        return $this->_cmsblockOptions;
    }

}
```

> app/code/Vendor/Name/Block/Adminhtml/Menu/Config/Backend/AdditionalBreadcrumb.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Name\Block\Adminhtml\Menu\Config\Backend;

use Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value as ConfigValue;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb;
use Magento\Framework\Model\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface;

class AdditionalBreadcrumb extends ConfigValue
{

    protected $serializer;

    public function __construct(
        SerializerInterface $serializer,
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        ScopeConfigInterface $config,
        TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
        AbstractResource $resource = null,
        AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $config, $cacheTypeList, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare data before save
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function beforeSave()
    {
        /** @var array $value */
        $value = $this->getValue();
        unset($value['__empty']);
        $encodedValue = $this->serializer->serialize($value);

        $this->setValue($encodedValue);
    }

    /**
     * Process data after load
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _afterLoad()
    {
        /** @var string $value */
        $value = $this->getValue();
        if($value) {
            $decodedValue = $this->serializer->unserialize($value);

            $this->setValue($decodedValue);
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: i want  to add it in admin form

Comment: hello there how i can add textarea in system.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
<dynamicRows name="dynamic_rows">
    <settings>
        <addButtonLabel translate="true">Add Record</addButtonLabel>
        <additionalClasses>
            <class name="admin__field-wide">true</class>
        </additionalClasses>
        <componentType>dynamicRows</componentType>
    </settings>
    <container name="record" component="Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">container</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="field_1" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label>Field #1</label>
            </settings>
        </field>
        
    </container>
</dynamicRows>
```

Reference :  https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-dynamicrows.html