# Magento 2 : Add Dynamic Option for custom form in admin

Tags: magento2, forms

I want to add dynamic input field for my custom admin form.
I have found a solution :[How to create a dynamic fields in admin form?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/264423/how-to-create-a-dynamic-fields-in-admin-form) but it's for system configuration and I want this option in my custom form.
Here you can see I have created the form:

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    /** @var Event $model */
    $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('vendor_test');

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
    $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
        ['data' => ['id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post']]
    );

    $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('branch_');

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
        'base_fieldset',
        ['legend' => __('Branch'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
    );

    if ($model->getId()) {
        $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'id']);
    }       

    $fieldset->addField(
        'address',
        'textarea',
        ['name' => 'address', 'label' => __('Address'), 'title' => __('Address')]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'phone',
        'text',
        ['name' => 'phone', 'label' => __('Phone'), 'title' => __('Phone')]
    );        

    $form->setValues($model->getData());
    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

Comment: please refer to this document it will help you to create dynamic rows https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-dynamicrows.html

Comment: @sandeshs, I am not using UI component